# How to make two thread wait for each other outcome?

Tags: java, multithreading

Here is my example code.

```
class A implements Runnable{

//stuff
Thread thr = new Thread(this);
boolean flag;
public void run()
{
    while(true){
        if(condition)flag = true;
    }
}
}



class B implements Runnable{

//stuff
A a = new A();
Thread thr = new Thread(this);
public void run()
{
    while(true){
    //i ll do some thing here
    if(a.flag == true)System.out.println("Kaboom");
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    B b = new B();
}
}
```

So the thing is i start b before a and i want b to wait until a.flag == true to fire "Kaboom" and a.thr have to wait when b doing its work in run() method. I tried this but it doesnt work

```
class A implements Runnable{

//stuff
Thread thr = new Thread(this);
boolean flag;
public void run()
{
    while(true){
        if(condition)flag = true;
    synchronized(B.class){

        this.flag=true;
        B.class.notifyAll();
    }
    }
}
}



class B implements Runnable{

//stuff
A a = new A();
Thread thr = new Thread(this);
public void run()
{
    while(true){
    synchronized(this){

        while(a.flag!=true)
        {
            this.wait();
        }}
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    B b = new B();
}}
```

There must be a problem in my synchronized block but i dont know what.
This probably a stupid question but i'm just a beginner in JAVA and i dont really get those Thread stuff and how it work. Plz help me

Comment: Have you considered using a Thread.Join() that way the A will have to finish before B starts. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html

Comment: the join() method will kill the thread and i dont want that to happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like your original approach of using wait / notifyAll to make the Thread doesn't use the CPU until the condition is met for it to resume running. Here's a solution that keeps this approach.

A few notes:

1 - Be careful when synchronizing on a class object. Unless you really want to synchronize the whole class, create an Object and use it as a lock.

2 - Use the `volatile` keyword to ensure that Java doesn't create a thread local version of the variable and that changes to it's value are instantly reflected to other threads.

```
public class Threads {
    private final Object lock = new Object();
    private volatile boolean flag;

    class RunnableA implements Runnable {
        private volatile boolean condition = false;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                if (condition) {
                    if (!flag) {
                        synchronized (lock) {
                            System.out.println("Setting Flag to True");
                            flag = true;
                            lock.notifyAll();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Condition is False");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class RunnableB implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                while (flag == false) {
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        if (flag == false) {
                            try {
                                lock.wait();
                            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Kaboom");
            }
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        RunnableA runnableA = new RunnableA();
        RunnableB runnableB = new RunnableB();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(runnableA);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(runnableB);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

        }
        runnableA.condition = true;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Threads().run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for ur help but this doesnt seem to work in my case. Can i put my problem this way. So you all know the game snake right? My idea is create 2 runnable class, class A is the snake head(press arrow and it ll move till it reach the edge) and class B for the frame to randomly generate "food" in the frame. The frame can only generate food if the previous food got eaten already. So the B object have to wait till A object eat the food. Could you tell me how to make that work sir?

Comment: i think the key here is to reset the flag to false after the snake ate the food but i dont know where to put that command.

Comment: So, whenever the head "eats" the food, you need to reset the flag and call notify on the lock that you are using on the food creator thread. Just use the same thread the thread is using.

Having said that, is there any special reason to create the game as multi-threaded? It's usually simpler to create it single threaded.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice i just created that game single threaded.

Answer (score 0):

You created a Runnable but did not start it in a thread.

Proper one:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.*;

class A implements Runnable {
    AtomicBoolean flag;
    AtomicBoolean condition;

    A() {
        flag = new AtomicBoolean();
        condition = new AtomicBoolean();
    }

    public void run(){
        while (true) {
        System.out.println("A");
        if (condition.get()) {
            flag.set(true);
            return ;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
}

class B implements Runnable {
    A a;

    B() {
        a = new A();
    }

    public void run() {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("B");
        if (a.flag.get()) {
            System.out.println("Kaboom");
            return ;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        new Thread(b).start();
        new Thread(b.a).start();
        b.a.condition.set(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ChiếnTrần Updated. BTW, you can read the book 'Java Concurrency in Practice' which is really great.

Comment: As a note, AtomicBoolean is a bit of an overkill for this problem (although it doesn't hurt). Reading or writing a boolean is atomic by itself. Unless you are using something like getAndSet or compareAndSet, that ensures atomic read and write, you'll be fine by using a regular boolean, although you should declare it volatile to avoid the JVM making copies of it between threads.

Comment: @andreban Oh, thx. I thought too much, this could be simpler.